# How to setup multiple terminals in VSCode

Tags: git, terminal, visual-studio-code, windows-10, anaconda

I'd like to have the option of having multiple terminals in VSCode, so that I can cycle between them as needed. I was after the following:

1. Powershell
2. CMD Prompt with Anaconda Prompt
3. Git Bash

Here are the VSCode settings I entered:

```
    // Powershell for default Python 3.6.4
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",

    // Access to Git hub bash within VS Code
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",

    // CMD line prompt with Anaconda Prompt + Args 
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",

    // The command line arguments to use when on the Windows terminal.
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"],
```

Unfortunately, when I now hit "shift + ~" I only get Anaconda Prompt. How do I have multiple Terminals appear in my terminal drop down menu to cycle through the above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.
Perhaps you should look at extensions.

This one? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-terminals

Or this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher

Comment: Actually it is possible, On traversy youtube channel he adds Git Bash to the terminal - here's the [video link]( https://youtu.be/fnPhJHN0jTE?t=7m40s) and here's a [blog post on adding Anaconda Terminal]( https://mscodingblog.blogspot.com.au/2017/08/setup-integrated-terminal-in-vs-code-to.html) My problem is that it now defaults to the anaconda terminal and I don't have multiple terminals to select from in the drop down window.

Comment: Here's the official documentation for adding multiple terminals, I'll give it another try once I get back home from work. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: In the doc, I see having multiple same shell and choosing the shell you want to open but nothing to open different shells...

Answer (score 0):

Now you can by using terminal profiles - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "PowerShell": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    "icon": "terminal-powershell"
  },
  "GitBash": {
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "icon": "terminal-bash",
    "icon": "terminal-bash"
  },
  "AnacondaCmd": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "args": ["/K", "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"],
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
  },
},
```